# How to rotate photo in SkyDrive

Tags: photo-sharing, onedrive

How can I rotate photo, that I have uploaded to SkyDrive album without the need of deleting and re-uploading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. SkyDrive does not *yet* have a feature to rotate photos.

PS: After I wrote the above line, I checked the official [SkyDrive Help & How To](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/SkyDrive-rotate-photos-faq). They confirm what I wrote:

> You currently can't rotate photos using SkyDrive. If you have the
>   SkyDrive app installed on your computer, you can open photos in your
>   SkyDrive folder and rotate them in a simple photo viewer such as
>   Windows Photo Viewer. When you close the files, your changes will be
>   saved and the photos will be automatically updated on SkyDrive.
>
> Tip: To edit your photos, you'll need to use a photo-editing program
>   like Photo Gallery before uploading them to SkyDrive. [Photo
>   Gallery](http://g.live.com/1rewlive4-web/en/wlsetup-web.exe??WLI=1) is a free program that you can use to edit and publish
>   photos directly to SkyDrive.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive now lets you rotate photos, if you are the owner. In OneDrive, select one photo either by opening it to full screen or by ticking the box. The rotate option will now be viewable.

As an extra note, you must be the owner of the photo to get the rotate options. People who you share the photo with, even 'edit' access will not be able to rotate your photo.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, Microsoft seem to have added it:

- Click on the image so it goes full screen;
- Click on the **Rotate** button on the bar up the top (to the right of *Manage*);

Note that this only seems to affect the image while it's on SkyDrive/OneDrive. Once downloaded it seems to revert to the original orientation.